# Two dictionaries intersection C#

Tags: c#

I had two DateTime lists and was intersecting them with no problems:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> both = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

I have the custom data type and still need to find the intersection:

```
public class AssetRecord
{
    // Custom data type. Each object has time and price
    public DateTime AssetDate { get; set; } 
    public double AssetPrice { get; set; }
}

// Lits initialization
public static List<AssetRecord> list1 = new List<AssetRecord> { }; 
// Key/Values - Date/Price. Custom data type is used to store an object in the collection
public static List<AssetRecord> list2 = new List<AssetRecord> { };
```

The problem is that IEnumerable takes only DataTime lists as an input and I do not have that data type anymore. Is it possible to find intersection using custom types? Or is it possible to take only Date field from created data type and convert it to List and then pass it to IEnumerable?

Comment: Override the equals method of the assetrecord function to check if the two fields inside match...that should work

Comment: You need to define equality for your type (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type), or use a custom `IEqualityComparer<AssetRecord>` in the overload of `Enumerable.Intersect` that takes two paramters (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: ... or implement an IEqualityComparer<T> and use the overload of Intersect

Comment: @JohnKane how do i do that? And how should i use Equals method in the Intersect?

Comment: @DiegoSlinger Read the docs. It is well documented and there are countless samples on the web

Comment: `Intersect` calls `Equals` itself in the overload you're using, you just need to implement it. If you _don't_ want to define equality on your type, you need to implement an `IEqualityComparer` and pass an instance of it to `Intersect`.

Comment: @SirRufo Thx Cap! Good advise - google your problem...

Comment: If you use a tuple with two fields instead of a custom class ..or an inherited tuple all this is done automatically

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that IEnumerable takes only DataTime lists

Huh? That makes no sense. `IEnumerable<T>` takes whatever `T` you choose. In this case `IEnumerable<AssetRecord>` will contain `AssetRecord`s.

Now, that is not your main problem. Your issue is with how intersect works. `Enumerable.Intersect<T>` takes the default equality of `T`. So, what is the default equality comparer of `AssetRecord`? Reference equality, and you probably want value equality semantics.

Solution? Override `Equals` in `AssetRecord` accordingly and while your at it implement `IEquatable<AssetRecord>` too (and don't forget to override `GetHashCode` with a consistent behavior):

```
public class AssetRecord: //IEquatable<AssetRecord> left as exercise
{   
    // Custom data type. Each object has time and price
    public DateTime AssetDate { get; set; } 
    public decimal AssetPrice { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
         if (other is AssetRecord)
         {
             var ass = (AssetRecord)other;
             return ass.AssetDate == AssetDate &&
                    ass.AssetPrice == AssetPrice;  
         }

         return false;
    }              

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return AssetDate.GetHashCode() ^ AssetPrice.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If you can't touch `AssetRecord` then implement an `IEqualityComparer<AssetRecord>` and use the corresponding overload of `Intersect`.

Two more issues with your code worth mentioning:

1. Prices should be a `decimal`, not a `double`. You want *exact* decimal values, use the right tool provided by the framework.
2. Your type is already named `AssetRecord`, it should probably be named `Asset`, but anyway, there is no need to have properties with redundant information. `Price` and `Date` should be enough.

Comment: What does ass mean in your context? And what does => mean? i don't see it in docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type @InBetween

Comment: @DiegoSlinger C# 6-7 syntax.

Comment: I don't understand. I am not that advanced in programming yet

Comment: @DiegoSlinger Changed syntax to more traditional c#.